# How to define and solve mutually referencing expressions in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

Suppose I have the following system of equations:

```
x = 1/y + b
y = 2*x
```

It follows that `b = x-1/(2*x)`

If I try to define these expressions in SymPy though,

```
from sympy import *
b = symbols('b')
x = 1/y + b
y = 2*x
```

it gives me

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-5a9b5f6b923e> in <module>()
      1 from sympy import *
      2 b = symbols('b')
----> 3 x = 1/y + b
      4 y = 2*x
      5 

NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

What's the proper way to set up this set of equations so that I can solve it for x?  Extending that, how to do an evalf on it?

Comment: `=` operator is not what you have understood so far. It assigns values to variables. You cannot use undefined variable in an expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `solve` to solve your equations.

```
In [1]: from sympy import *

In [2]: from sympy.abc import x, y, b

In [3]: eq1 = Eq(x - 1/y - b, 0)

In [4]: eq2 = Eq(2*x - y, 0)

In [5]: solve([eq1, eq2], b)
Out[5]: {b: x - 1/y}
```

Comment: This is working for my RL application, but I'm finding that the final answer is displaying in terms of the intermediate equations, rather than the base variables that I'm looking for.  Is there a way to forcefully expand the result?  I tried expand() but it doesn't like the fact that the answer is a dictionary.

Comment: Similarly, how do I run an evalf() or equivalent on the result?

Comment: that gets me an expression for b = wawa, but I'm having trouble doing evalf() on it.  It won't seem to plug the formulas in the way I expect it to.

Comment: I would suggest you to create an issue in the SymPy's issue tracker if you think that it's not behaving as expected. https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues
Also provide the link to this question.

Answer (score 2):

`=` expression is not does what you think.
In regular python syntax the `=` operator used for variable assignment.
You should define everything in symbols then convert equation to be equal to zero and solve it.
The main problem is the lack of general procedural programming knowledge.

You should use `solvers` which requires the equation to be expressed as the following.

```
x = 1/y + b
x - 1/y - b = 0
```

The code could be written as following.

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import symbols

b = symbols('b')
x = symbols('x')
y = 2 * x

solve(x - 1/y - b, b)
```

Then the output will be what you want to see.

```
>>> [x - 1/(2*x)]
```

If you want to express b in terms of `y` the following code could be used.

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import symbols

b = symbols('b')
y = symbols('y')
x = y/2

solve(x - 1/y - b, b)
```

Then the output will be:

```
>>> [y/2 - 1/y]
```

If you want to express b in terms of both x and y you could use the following (thanks to Sudhanshu Mishra's answer):

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import symbols, Eq

b = symbols('b')
y = symbols('y')
x = symbols('x')

eq1 = Eq(1/y + b, x)
eq2 = Eq(2 * x, y)

solve([eq1, eq2], b)
```

The result will be:

```
>>> {b: x - 1/y}
```